# Does the stack grow continuously?

Tags: c, memory, stack

I'm wondering why this code isn't working as expected.

```
typedef char uint8;

  int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  // insert code here...

  uint8 number_1 = 3;
  uint8 number_2 = 1;
  uint8 *PointerToNumber = &number_1;

  printf("%d \n", *PointerToNumber);
  ++PointerToNumber;
  printf("%d \n", *PointerToNumber);

  return 0;
}
```

This program prints 3 and -112. However shouldn't it print 3 and 1 if the stack grows continuously?

So if I'm pointing to number_1 and then increasing the pointer address of type uint8 shouldn't it then point to number_2 since it was declared right after number_2?

Comment: This isn't a matter of which way the stack grows, it's a matter of how the compiler chooses to arrange local variables.

Comment: There may be unused bytes between the two variables... and there's no guarantee of the variables being placed in any particular location or order, or even being included at all (they could be optimised away depending on how they're used).

Comment: You can't depend on where local variables are located in memory, but `number_2` is probably at the next lower address after `number_1`.

Comment: Your assumptions on how the variables are laid out are invalid as already explained by the comments above. If you want to know that information then you need to disassemble the code to see exactly how the compiler has arranged those variables.

Comment: There is no stack in the C language. Your code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: The stack is not mentioned in the C language definition. It's an implementation detail.

Comment: @user148013: Arrogance is a bad replacement for knowledge. Read the standard and learn about implementations. Neither does the standard require a stack (nor a heap, btw.), nor do all implementations use a stack for automatic variables (some can suse different memory models). Even on x64 or ARRM small functions might not use the stack for local variables. You might be surprised what a modern compiler will do! So learn!

Comment: allright, I will do my best! Any resources that explain what you are talking about any further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
++PointerToNumber;
printf("%d \n", *PointerToNumber);
```

is cause for undefined behavior. It's pointless trying to justify any behavior. The behavior of the program could change with changes to optimization level, different compiler options, and a different compiler.

In this case, an optimizer could choose not to allocate any space for `number_2` since it is not used in the function.

Answer (score 0):

All right as someone commented, number-2 is probably at the next lower address after number_1. 
So instead of doing ++PointerToNumber, --PointerToNumber creates the expected result (printing "1").

Comment: Again, no guarantees.  Try compiling with optimisations on and see if it still works.  Also, with optimisations off I get the result you're expecting with your original code simply because my compiler ordered the variables differently than yours did... and with optimisations on, neither works.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that. I just wanted to verify the overall concept of the stack as LIFO memory.

Comment: The placement of local variables is not related to the stack being LIFO. What typically happens when a function is called is that the caller pushes the parameters and the return address onto the stack and calls the function. The called function then sets the frame pointer to the value of the stack pointer. The stack pointer is then decremented by the amount of space the function needs for local storage. The local variables are assigned locations in that space (expressed as negative offsets from the frame pointer), but they could be anywhere in there. That's totally up to the compiler.